# How can I start a background process in python?

Tags: python-2.7, process, background

I want to make python start a background process. I am trying to make a 1v1 chat and I don't know how to verify `always` if new messages come in. Is there a library I can do this with?
Something like this:

```
def always(x):
    always program are running:
    if x != '': print x

while True:
    always(server.recv(1024))
    data = raw_input('>>>')
    client.send(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your background process, I would create a [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['your_background_command'])
stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate()
```

Then you can use [`returncode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) to check on the status of the process.

```
print process.returncode
```